# CSS3 Looping after last frame animation is done in sequence of animations

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I currently have 5 frames - each frame consist of a total of 3 animations that by time gradually fade up the next frame.

My issue: How can I loop the animation after having finished the last sequence of animation? (in the example that would be #frame2)

I don't mind using javascript to possibly detect and "force" the loop.

**Fiddle here**: http://jsfiddle.net/a0cpo5xe/1/ - My setup looks as so (just imagine it with 5 frames):

```
#frame1 {
    animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay:0.8s;
}

#picture-1 .blink {
    animation:kf_frame_fade_down 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay:0.5s;
}
#picture-1 .picture {
    animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay:0.5s;
}

#frame2 {
    animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay:4.3s;
}

#picture-2 .blink {
    animation:kf_frame_fade_down 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay:4s;
}
#picture-2 .picture {
    animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay:4s;
}

/* FADES */
@keyframes kf_frame_fade_up {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes kf_frame_fade_down {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Can you put together a quick jsFiddle with your content please?

Comment: Infinite loop is definitely possible but we would need to see your HTML structure to be able to answer this question (if not a demo).

Comment: Tahir - u bet - just done that. Im actually looking to loop it 3 times

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the `animationend` event using JavaScript to determine if the animation ended.

[**animationend**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend)

> The animationend event is fired when a CSS animation has completed.

Here is an example repeating your css animation from your jsfiddle three times by cloning your elements, removing them and at the end of the animation adding them back to the DOM.

I'm sure you will get the idea.

```js
var i = 1;

function whichAnimationEvent(){
  var t,
      el = document.createElement("fakeelement"),
      animations = {
        "animation"      : "animationend",
        "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
      };

  for (t in animations){
    if (el.style[t] !== undefined){
      return animations[t];
    }
  }
}

function init() {
  var animationEvent = whichAnimationEvent(),
      wrp = document.getElementById('wrapper'),
      frm2 = document.getElementById('frame2'),
      cln = wrp.cloneNode(true);

  function animationEnd(evt) {
    i++;
    //console.log(evt);
    wrp.parentNode.removeChild(wrp);
    document.body.appendChild(cln);
    if (i !== 3) {
      init();
    }

  }

  frm2.addEventListener(animationEvent, animationEnd);
}

init();
```

```css
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#frames {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  opacity: 0; /* hide */
}

#pictures {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.picture {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0; /* hide */
}

/* ANIMATION START */
#frame1 {
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.4s;
  animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.8s;
  animation-delay:0.8s;
}

#picture-1 .picture {
  background-color: #116343;
  -webkit-animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.2s;
  animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s;
  animation-delay:0.5s;
}

#frame2 {
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.4s;
  animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay:4s;
  animation-delay:4s;
}

#picture-2 .picture {
  background-color: #3d1163;
  -webkit-animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.2s;
  animation:kf_frame_fade_up 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay:3.7s;
  animation-delay:3.7s;
}

/* FADES */
@-webkit-keyframes kf_frame_fade_up {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes kf_frame_fade_up {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes kf_frame_fade_down {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes kf_frame_fade_down {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="frames">
    <div id="frame1" class="frame">frame 1</div>
    <div id="frame2" class="frame">frame 2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="pictures">
    <div id="picture-1">
      <div class="picture">pic 1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="picture-2">
      <div class="picture">pic 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```